# Trying to save an object into post meta with wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editpost

Tags: block-editor, api

I am using wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editpost to try and save an object as a value into post meta. I keep getting an error saying. "Updating failed. firstName is not a valid property of Object"
Here is a simple example of what I am trying.

Register post meta

```
            $post_type = ''; 
            register_post_meta( $post_type, '_example_meta_key', [
                'auth_callback' => function() {
                    return current_user_can('edit_posts');
                },
                'show_in_rest'      => true,
                'single'            => true,
                'type'              => 'object',
            ]);
```

In js file:

```
 let person = {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
    };
wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ meta: { _example_meta_key: person } })
```

I have added a new settings section using 'PluginDocumentSettingPanel' hook which captures the user input for the meta.

When I save the page I get an error in the page "Updating failed. firstName is not a valid property of Object."

I am sure it is something simple, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the Object Meta Type section of the Modifying Responses page](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#object-meta-type) in [the REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api):

> When registering `object` meta, setting the `type` to `object` is not sufficient, you also need to inform WordPress of what properties to allow. This is done by writing a JSON Schema when registering the metadata.

Interestingly, `register_meta()` will throw an error if you register an `array` type without a schema, but it doesn't seem to perform this check for the `object` type. I'm not clear on why.

The [schema format](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/) is an adaptation of [the JSON Schema Version 4 specification](https://json-schema.org/specification-links.html#draft-4), with a couple deviations.

In this case, a schema to describe an object such as `{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }` might look as such:

```php
register_post_meta( $post_type, '_example_meta_key', [
  'auth_callback' => function() {
    return current_user_can('edit_posts');
  },
  'show_in_rest'  => [
    'schema' => [
      'type'       => 'object',
      'properties' => [
        'firstName' => [
          'type' => 'string',
        ],
        'lastName'  => [
          'type' => 'string',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
  'single'       => true,
  'type'         => 'object',
]);
```

Also note that when registering meta for a post type for use in REST API interactions, it is required that the post type has `custom-fields` support. While you can use an empty string to address all available post types, when interacting with meta for a post over the REST API (such as through Gutenberg APIs), the operation will fail if the post's post type does not support `custom-fields`.

### Addendum: Dynamic Properties Schema

If you're unsure of what the keys of your properties will be or how many there might be, you can use [the `additionalProperties` keyword](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/#additionalproperties) in the object schema to specify a schema for all other properties which are not otherwise addressed.

[The `object` type](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/#objects) supports a number of additional keywords and constraints to further define an object's schema as well.

In the case described in the comments, a schema to describe the object

```js
{
  default_profile: { isRestricted: true },
  profile_one: { isRestricted: true },
  profile_two: { isRestricted: true },
}
```

with unknown "profile names" / an unknown number of profile entries could be written as such:

```
  'show_in_rest'  => [
    'schema' => [
      'type'                 => 'object',
      'additionalProperties' => [
        'type'       => 'object',
        'properties' => [
          'isRestricted' => [
            'type' => 'boolean',
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just messing with the schema aspect when I saw your reply. I got it to work, but now I have a more complex schema that has me stumped. How do I configure this scheme 
    ` let access = {
      default_profile: { isRestricted: true },
      profile_one: { isRestricted: true },
      profile_two: { isRestricted: true }
    };
     wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ meta: { _example_meta_key: access } 
    })`
The 'profile_one' and 'profile_two' are dynamically created based on what a user names the profile. So it could be any name. How would I configure the schema?

Comment: Yeah, sorry! I misread that the first time through - I've corrected the example :)

Comment: Thanks, I figured that you misread it. The example makes more sense. I will have to try it later and get back to you. I owe you for all the help

Comment: That worked. Need to do further testing, but I think it is what I need. Thanks again @bosco